# Using the Context API as a way of mimicking useSelector and useDispatch with redux v5

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I'm working on a React project where I'm constrained to using React Redux v5, which doesn't include `useDispatch` and `useSelector`.

Nonetheless I really would like to have these hooks (or something like them) available in my app.
Therefore, I've created a wrapper component at the top level of the app which I connect using redux's `connect` function.
My mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps then just look like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: DispatchType) => {
    return {
        dispatch,
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: StateType) => {
    return {
        state,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout);
```

In my wrapper component, I then pass the dispatch and the state into the value:

```
  <DispatchContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
{children}
</DispatchContext.Provider>
```

Finally, I have a hook that looks like this:

```
const useSelectAndDispatch = () => {
    const context = useContext(DispatchContext);
    if (context === null) {
        throw new Error("Please use useDispatch within DispatchContext");
    }
    const { state, dispatch } = context;

    function select(selector) {
        return selector(state);
    }
    return { dispatch, select };
};
```

I then use dispatch and selector in my components via useSelectAndDispatch.

I was wondering if this is an appropriate way to go about this issue, and whether I can expect any performance problems. I am using reselect, and have a good understanding of memoization. I'm just looking for opinions, since I've heard that the redux team held off implementing `useDispatch` and `useSelector` for a long time because of performance issues.

Many thanks for any opinions!

Comment: Can you clarify why you're stuck on React-Redux v5? It _should_ be safe to update straight to React-Redux v7 or v8, at least at the API level. The only real potential migration issue is libraries that tried to use undocumented access to RR v5's `context.store`, such as older versions of `redux-form` and `connected-react-router`. As long as you're not using libs like those, you _should_ be able to just update straight to RR v7/v8.

Comment: Also, per the "held off on implementing hooks due to perf reasons": this sounds like a garbled version of what happened. In reality, React-Redux v6 had perf issues, per https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1177 . We had to rewrite that and release v7 first. _That_ allowed us to implement a hooks API, because we'd fixed how our internals worked. Also see [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) for details.

Comment: Hi @markerikson, thanks for the explanation - just to clarify, this was actually a problem I encountered at work. It's a big company with a large codebase and quite a bespoke build process. I'm fairly junior (I'm sure my code above demonstrates it!) but a senior eng did say we'd be upgrading soon. I'll check out those links, and thanks again for getting back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cause significant peformance problems. Your mapStateToProps is using the entire state object, so every time anything changes in the state, the provider must rerender. And since the provider rerendered with a new value, so too must every component that consumes the context. In short, you will be forcing most of your app to rerender anytime anything changes.

Instead of using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps, i would go back to the actual store object, and build your hooks from that. Somewhere in your app is presumably a line of code that says `const store = createStore(/* some options */)`.

Using that `store` variable, you can then make some hooks. If i can assume that there's only one store in your app, then the dispatch hook is trivial:

```
import { store } from 'wherever the store is created'

export const useMyDispatch = () => {
  return store.dispatch;
}
```

And the selector one would be something like this. It uses `.subscribe` to be notified when something in the store changes, and then it uses the selector to pluck out the part of the state that you care about. If nothing changed, then the old state and new state will pass an === check, and react skips rendering. If it has changed though, the component renders (only the component that called useMySelect plus its children, not the entire app)

```
export const useMySelector = (selector) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    return selector(store.getState());
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      const newValue = selector(store.getState());
      setValue(newValue);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  return value;
}
```

Comment: I would have to recommend _against_ this, specifically because it ultimately relies on directly importing `store` into the hooks file, and then importing _that_ across the rest of the codebase. That's not safe, and can lead to circular import errors.

Comment: If circular imports are a problem, or if there are multiple stores, you can augment this solution by importing `store` in a top level component only, providing the store via context, and then having the two hooks get `store` from that context instead of from an import.

Comment: @markerikson given the constraint to v5, do you think I'd be best off just going with the connect pattern and avoiding hooks altogether? Or does Nicholas Tower's context solution to the imports issue seem feasible?

Comment: The snippets ought to _run_, at least. But I'm not sure I'd necessarily recommend going with them in a production app, especially because they don't account for a lot of actual edge cases. Tbh I'd probably just stick with `connect` for now until you have a change to upgrade to v7 or v8.